# Clipping String to a given index

Tags: java, string, cpu-word, truncate, html

I have a String and I want to clip it at a given index. In the scenario The String might contain HTML tag and I have to skip those tags while clipping.

For example if the String is:

```
"Les pirates ont<br/>attaqué des douzaines de sites Web français";
```

and I want to clip it at 25 so that I can get `Les pirates ont<br/>attaqué...`. Also I cannot slice a word from middle, while clipping if I get that the character at the clipping point is not a space then I have to backtrack the String from that point until I cannot find a space. If any space found then I will cut upto that index.

Here is the code I tried, but it is looping infinitely:

```
public class Test {

    private String value = "Les pirates ont<br/>attaqué des douzaines de sites Web français";
    private int clipAt = 25;

    public Test() {
        run();
    }

    private void run() {
        String elipsis = "...";
        int originalLength = value.length();
        int cliplength = clipAt - elipsis.length();
        String clipedValue = value;

        if (originalLength > cliplength) {
            char character = value.charAt(cliplength + 1);

            while (character != ' ') {
                if(character == '>'){                   
                    cliplength += count(value.substring(0, cliplength+2));       
                }

                cliplength = cliplength - 1;
                character = value.charAt(cliplength + 1);                

            }
            clipedValue = value.substring(0, cliplength + 1)+elipsis;
        } 
        System.out.println(clipedValue);
    }

    private int count(String str){      
        int length = str.length() - 1;
        char character = str.charAt(length);
        int count = 0;
        while(character != '<'){
            length--;
            character = str.charAt(length);
            count++;
        }
        System.out.println(count);
        return count;
    }

    public static void main(String... args){
        new Test();
    }
}
```

Any information will be very helpful to me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Parsing html is not an easy task. HTML is not regular language, so regex will not help you...
However you may find [htmlunit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/) helpful. Also check [the options for HTML scrapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2861/options-for-html-scraping)

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

A slight confusion arises what if the text is say `"I am feeling <html> too good </html> today."`, and now suppose i say clip at 14, so am i suppose to return this String `"I am feeling <html>..."` or something else ?

Try this code, Hope this will solve the part :

```
public class ClipText
{
    private void clipString(String text, int endIndex)
    {
        int i = endIndex;
        String result = new String();
        do
        {
            if (Character.isWhitespace(text.charAt(endIndex)))
            {
                result = text.substring(0, endIndex);
                result = result + "...";
                break;
            }   
            else
            {
                endIndex++;
                i++;
            }               
        }while(i <= endIndex);
        System.out.println("Result : " + result);
    }

    public static void main(String... args)
    {
        String text = "Les pirates ont<br/>attaqué des douzaines de sites Web français";
        int endIndex = 6;
        new ClipText().clipString(text, endIndex);
    }
}
```